# Read USB port on Raspberry Pi Pico without pyserial

Tags: serial-port, usb, micropython, raspberry-pi-pico, usbserial

I'm trying to read from a USB-connected device connected to a Raspberry Pi Pico using MicroPython. In CPython it's done using [pyserial](https://github.com/pyserial/pyserial):

```py
import serial # <-- not available in micropython

ser = serial.Serial()
ser.baudrate = 115200
ser.bytesize = serial.EIGHTBITS
ser.parity = serial.PARITY_NONE
ser.stopbits = serial.STOPBITS_ONE
ser.xonxoff = 0
ser.rtscts = 0
ser.timeout = 12

# configure usb port
ser.port = "/dev/ttyUSB0"
ser.close()

try:
    ser.open()

    raw_msg = ser.readline()
    decoded = raw_msg.decode('ascii').strip()
except:
    sys.exit(f'Error on {ser.name}')
finally:
    ser.close
```

pyserial isn't available in MicroPython. How can I do this without pyserial?